# Can't install mogenerator

Tags: ios, macos, homebrew, mogenerator

I'm running `brew install mogenerator`

And unfortunately receive error:

```
Error: Failure while executing: /usr/bin/otool -L /usr/bin/install_name_tool
```

What may be a possible reason?

I tried running `/usr/bin/otool -L /usr/bin/install_name_tool` and received the following output:

```
xcodebuild[1597:47878] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID AABB7188-E14E-4433-AD3B-5CD791EAD9A3 for plug-in at  path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/Alcatraz.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
2016-06-18 13:39:49.180 xcodebuild[1597:47878] Failed to load plugin at: /Users/andreychernukha/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/Alcatraz.xcplugin, skipping.  Reason for failure: *** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]
xcodebuild: error: SDK "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk" cannot be located.
otool: error: unable to find utility "otool", not a developer tool or in PATH
```

Comment: And what is wrong with this question?

Comment: have you tried executing `/usr/bin/otool -L /usr/bin/install_name_tool` in a shell and see what happens?

Comment: see my updated question

Comment: hmh, weird. I would try to reinstall Xcode and see if that helps.

Comment: Seems like a fairly valid question. Im guessing its a bit "solve my google research task for me" - Searching the error indicates that something you have done has farked your command line tools. Xcode or OS install maybe. Is it happening for all brew installs? Or maybe just install from the .dmg https://rentzsch.github.io/mogenerator/ and move on with your day :-)